# Creating Unit Tests for OrderSummary or other generated Objects

Tags: apex, lightning, unit-test, salesforcedx, lightning-experience

I have multiple methods that make queries to the OrderSummary.
I have tried to mock the call to the database using the Test.start() and Test.stop() to try to insert an OrderSummary, but that is not possible.
I also tried to use the Test.loadData() to load a OrderSummary CSV data from a static resource. It also gives me an error.
The last thing that I tried is to create the entire tree of an order to see if it create an OrderSummary:

1. Account
2. Product2
3. PricebookEntry
4. Order
5. OrderItem

But after all the inserts I still don't have the OrderSummary in my test. There must be a simple way to mock those kind of objects in Apex, but I cannot find an answer, I only find examples online using simple objects like Account and Contact.
Does someone knows how can I mock a return of a method or a call to database that uses the OrderSummary?

Comment: does your org satisfy `This object is only available in Salesforce Order Management orgs or if the B2B Commerce on Lightning Experience license is enabled.`

Comment: Yes, the object is available, but I can't mock it

Comment: if you are using the selector pattern, you can mock the query results using the JSON.deserialize technique --- many examples of this on stackexchange

Comment: This doesn't work for the methods that actually do the queries. There is no other way to mock an object like Order Summary?  In my current code base there are a lot of objects with the same problem, like PaymentAuthorization for example. There must be a better way to mock those types of objects.

Comment: i'm out of ideas here as our org doesn't use Salesforce Order Management